# Stripe Elements forcing a postal code

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

Stripe seems to be handling ZIP/postalcodes incorrectly when it comes to using their Stripe Elements API. This issue occurs only when the elements are split-up into parts, such as Card Number, ZIP, and CVC, as opposed to using the all-in-one solution that they offer.

If you go to the stripe elements example page located here:
https://stripe.com/elements/examples

And take a look at example 2 (the one with the yellow Pay button), stripe forces the user to input a postal code even when the country tied to the credit-card does not use one (Hong-Kong, for instance).

You can easily test this using Stripe's own International Test Card Numbers.

If you try to click the Pay button without entering a zip, you get the error,

> Your postal code is incomplete.

which is incorrect.

[image: You can see that in this image here]

Many countries simply don't require a postcode - so this renders the examples on the Stripe page useless for any country that does not require a postcode.

Their internal code seems to be able to determine the internationalization of the card, because the all-in-one examples HIDE the zip field for this case.

Doe anyone see a way around this error?

**UPDATE 11/2/2017**

They have since fixed this bug, and the postal code should no longer be required in countries that do not require it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Seems like a big enough issue that you should bring it up to the group monitored by Stripe themselves. https://groups.google.com/a/lists.stripe.com/forum/#!forum/api-discuss

Answer (score 13):

CardElement accepts all the options as defined [here](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#element-options)

```
<div className='p-3' style={{ backgroundColor: '#F5F6FA' }}>
   <CardElement hidePostalCode={true} />
</div>
```

Creating your card element from JS:

```
creditCard = elements.create('card', {
    hidePostalCode : true
});
```

Answer (score 7):

To create your card element without the postal code from JS:

```
let stripe = Stripe(yourStripeKey);
let elements = stripe.elements({
    // your options here...
});

let creditCard = elements.create('card', {
   hidePostalCode : true
});

creditCard.mount("#creditCard");
```